# How to see http requests in fiddler going to docker container on windows?

Tags: http, docker, fiddler

I'm using default docker on windows configuration and I run configure an application like this:

`docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name openproject ...`

I can access the application using browser, but in fiddler I can't see traffic to the docker container. I see other traffic, so I assume the browser has correct proxy settings.

I've set proxy in docker settings to fiddler (http://127.0.0.1:8888), but still nothing from the container is visible to fiddler.

Comment: 'fiddler I can't see traffic to the docker container' -- What's the client application that sends traffic /into/ Docker? If it's a browser, what URL are you using?

Comment: Clients are a browser and powershell. Url is "https://localhost:8080" and "https://127.0.0.1:8080". Works in the browser and powershell, though fiddler does not see it.

Comment: Which browser, specifically? .NET clients, like Powershell don't proxy traffic to `127.0.0.1`; you can use `localhost.fiddler` instead. See http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET

Comment: Chrome and Firefox, hadn't tested IE. I use -Proxy parameter for Invoke-WebRequest, so powershell too should be visible. Other web pages are seen in fiddler after using either of them.

Comment: Powershell and .NET don't proxy requests to localhost/127.0.0.1, regardless of whether you specify a proxy. Requests from Chrome/Firefox absolutely should be shown. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/SsZnGxdxklg

Comment: They do, you have to configure the proxy parameter/settings properly: http://imgur.com/a/DSBUX

Comment: You misunderstand: .NET doesn't proxy requests whose URLs target `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`. (This isn't about the URL of the proxy, it's about the URL of the target resource). https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6359204-support-the-loopback-token-in-proxy-bypass-lists

Comment: Oh, I really misunderstand. You are right. Thank you for showing me that :) So the solution would be for docker to host on non-loopback IP. I'll check it out in a free moment.

Comment: Alternatively, use `localhost.fiddler` as the address you use to call the Docker container. Fiddler will get that address and automatically turn it into `localhost`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're trying to see traffic *exiting* the container, add this to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV http_proxy "http://host.docker.internal:8888/"
ENV https_proxy "http://host.docker.internal:8888/"
```

The http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables should be lowercase in a Linux container, contrary to what some of the Docker docs say (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212894/whats-the-right-format-for-the-http-proxy-environment-variable-caps-or-no-ca)

host.docker.internal shortcuts you to the internal IP address used by the host (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/).

Port 8888 is whatever port Fiddler is listening on in the host. (8888 is the default.)

Comment: This gives me errors while building the service:
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/sdk/manifests/6.0": unable to connect to HTTP proxy 192.168.1.96:8888

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by finding out the IP-address of your Docker host (the VM running on Hyper-V). Just run "ipconfig" on the command shell.

The default IP address is probably 10.0.75.1 (at least it is on my machine).

So instead of http://localhost:8080 browse to http://10.0.75.1:8080 and fiddler will pick up the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setup `http_proxy` env. doesn't work. HTTPS traffic is still encrypted and marked in Fiddler as `Tunnel to`.

[image]

After short analysis, it seems outgoing that HTTPS traffic from Docker cannot be decrypted.

## Solution

The solution is to import fiddler root certificate into Docker container:

1. In Fiddler options mark "Capture HTTPS CONNECT" and "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" options
2. Export Root Certificate
   [image]
3. Convert fiddler's certificate into der/pem format (e.g. using openssl or export from Windows Certificate Manager):

   ```bash
   openssl x509 -inform der -in FiddlerRoot.cer -out FiddlerRoot.pem
   ```
4. Replace main CA certificate in docker with Fiddler cert

   Docker compose:

   ```
   volumes:
     - .\FiddlerRoot.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:ro
   ```
5. Voilà, decrypted data from docker containers:
   [image]